# Python - explain function parameters

Tags: python

So I understand this simple `for` loop:

```
sum = 0
for number in {1,2,3,4}:
    sum = sum + number
    print sum

>>> 
1
3
6
10
>>>
```

Then here is a neat little code that combines a `for` loop and a function I found on the interwebs:

```
def sum_list(l):
    sum = 0
    for number in l:
        sum = sum + number
    return sum

print sum_list([1, 7, 4])

>>> 
12
```

What I don't understand is how python interprets this code (rather how Python knows to add the 3 arguments 1,7,4 together).

I would really help if you can break it down for me!

---

To tack on another question for you guys to review:

```
sum = 0
for number in {1,2,3,4}:
    sum = sum + number
    return sum
```

Spits out an error. `print sum` will list the results as `1,3,6,10`

Error says: ***Syntaxerror: 'return' outside of function***

---

**[EDIT] @sshashank124**

For example: This code spits out 3 answers. It prints out:

```
sum = 0
for number in {1,7,4}:
    sum = sum + number
    print sum

>>> 
1
8
12 
>>>
```

But this:

```
def sum_list(l):
    sum= 0
    for number in l:
        sum = sum + number
    print sum
print sum_list([1, 7, 4])

>>> 
12
none
```

Spits out only 1 answer, `12`. My question is why that occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It knows to add them together, because you tell it to do that.

Let me rewrite the code a bit to show what's happening. Rewrite one, adding 1,7,4 and then 2,8,5, but adding more numbers requires more lines:

```python
sum = 0
sum = sum + 1
sum = sum + 7
sum = sum + 4
print sum

sum = 0
sum = sum + 2
sum = sum + 8
sum = sum + 5
print sum
```

Rewrite two - using a loop. Two lines shorter, but it can now handle lists of more items - adding four, five, even ten numbers, without adding more lines of code, just by making the lists longer:

```python
sum = 0
for number in [1,7,4]:
    sum = sum + number
print sum

sum = 0
for number in [2,8,5]:
    sum = sum + number
print sum
```

Rewrite three - moving the lists out of the loop. The code got longer again, but something interesting happened - see how the loop code is now *identical* both times:

```python
myList = [1,7,4]
sum = 0
for number in myList:
    sum = sum + number
print sum

myList = [2,8,5]
sum = 0
for number in myList:
    sum = sum + number
print sum
```

Rewrite four - now it's identical, why does it have to be there twice? Can't we ... write it once, and use it twice? That way if we need to change it, we only have to change it in one place. Yes - make it a *function* and call the function:

```python
def sum_list():
    sum = 0
    for number in myList:
        sum = sum + number
    print sum

myList = [1,7,4]
sum_list()

myList = [2,8,5]
sum_list()
```

Rewrite five - what's happening above works fine, because you called everything 'myList' it all works. But if you write bigger programs like that it gets messy fast - one myList could be several pages of code away from another, we'll tend to forget that something pages and pages away could be affecting things. So we humans can keep track of what's going on, we need to clearly and explicitly give the function something to work on, and not have it just reaching far away and pulling things out of the rest of the code.

```python
def sum_list(working_list):       # working_list is whatever the function gets
    sum = 0                       # by a different name
    for number in working_list:
        sum = sum + number
    print sum

myList1 = [1,7,4]
sum_list(myList1)

myList2 = [2,8,5]
sum_list(myList2)
```

See in the above code, I've called them myList1 and myList2 - yet whatever you give to the function, the function sees it called 'working_list'. The names don't have to match.

But because sum_list has it's own name for whatever you give it, you don't have to have a name for what you give it. You can just give it a list directly without a name:

```python
def sum_list(working_list):
    sum = 0                
    for number in working_list:
        sum = sum + number
    print sum

sum_list([1,7,4])

sum_list([2,8,5])
```

The next move is, once you're feeding things into sum_list, sum_list is looking away and writing to the screen. We can't have that. For the sake of humans tracking what's happening, that's a bad idea - you want to give functions some work to do and have them give you back an answer. That way you know you can use them anytime you need, without worrying about them printing to the screen unexpectedly. That's where 'return' comes in:

```python
def sum_list(working_list):
    sum = 0                
    for number in working_list:
        sum = sum + number
    return sum

result = sum_list([1,7,4])
print result

result = sum_list([2,8,5])
print result
```

Now sum_list is a self contained adder, it does nothing else. You can trust it. It's not reading from names all over your code, it's only reading explicitly what you gave to it. It's not writing to the screen at surprise times, or anything. You give it a list, you get a result, it's isolated, limited, controlled, predictable, easy to work with, easy to reuse. And like the list names, if all you do is get the result and print it, you don't *need* to give that a name either:

```python
def sum_list(working_list):
    sum = 0                
    for number in working_list:
        sum = sum + number
    return sum

print sum_list([1,7,4])
print sum_list([2,8,5])
```

Edit: I hope that explains several of your questions.

1. What that code is doing
2. Why it prints one answer instead of three - because you are giving it one thing (a list).
3. Why it makes no sense to use `return` on its own - because you have to call a function and then return from the function, and you can bring something back with you or you can go somewhere and bring nothing back (function with no return). But you can't bring something back if you don't go anywhere first.

Comment: WOW, thanks for putting in all that effort. It's going to take some time to go through this, but I'm REALLY looking forward to it. Thanks again!

Comment: I noticed that the `print sum` inside the loop and outside the loop changes the outcome. If its inside, it lists `(1,5,12)`. If its outside the loop, it just gives the answer: `12`. Why is that?

Comment: @user3386440 because you're noodling around inside the machinery before it's finished. The code inside the loop happens once for every number in the list. Three numbers, it happens three times. So it adds something into sum and prints it. Next time it adds something to sum and prints it - the sum of the first two items in the list. Next time it adds something again and prints it - the sum of the first three items. When you put print outside, it does all the summing of all the numbers behind the scenes and you just get to see afterwards - or rather, you tell it to show you after it's finished.

Answer (score 2):

```
for number in l:
```

This iterates over the `l`, and `number` will have each and every element of `l` on every iteration. You can check that like this

```
for number in l:
    print number
# 1
# 7
# 4
```

You are adding those numbers to the `sum` variable. You can check that like this

```
sum = 0
for number in l:
    sum = sum + number
    print sum
# 1
# 8
# 12
```

I believe you are doing this for educational purpose. If you actually wanted to find the sum of an iterable, then you can use the builtin [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function, like this

```
sum([1, 7, 4])
```

Comment: I was about to ask. Why Python spits out one answer:`12` instead of three answers: `1,8,12`

Comment: @user3386440 Because, you are returning after adding all the numbers together. So, only one number will be returned and printed :)

Comment: If I replace `return` with `print`, it will give me: `12 none`, so still one integer.

Comment: It will immediately print the answer. However, if you do 'sum = sum_list([x, y, z])' Then you can reference that variable in later code.

Comment: @user3386440 Please include the `print` statement in the for loop itself, like in my answer.

Comment: Ok will do. I guess I don't quite understand `return` as well as I thought. `return sum` gives an error in the first for loop I gave, but works fine in the second.

Comment: @user3386440 Can you please show the complete code?

Comment: Sure, let me see if I can do this right: I'll add it to the OP? Unless there is an easier way?

Comment: @user3386440 There is no `return` statement in that code, right? Please show the problematic code with `return`

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to add a full piece of code in the comments while keeping formatting intact. So I added it to the bottom of the OP for your review. :)

Comment: @user3386440 You did the right thing :) But, you are returning the `sum` immediately after the first iteration. Its a minor logic error, but not a syntax error. Can you please post the actual error message as well.

Comment: logic errors, aye a pain in the butt. I'll add it to the OP. Sorry for making you work so hard. I sincerely appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3386440 As the error message says, you are using `return` statement not inside a function. You should be using it inside a function, like in the second version in your question.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm dumb, had no idea returns had to be used inside a function. Thanks again! Even reading the error message, it never occurred to me that what I was writing wasn't even a function. :P

Comment: @user3386440 Thats okay :) Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `for number in l:` line takes each of the elements in `[1,7,4]` and adds them to the sum variable which represents the total sum of the elements in the list.

This is what it looks like:

Take first element of `l`: `1`
Add to `sum` --> `sum` is now `1`

Take second element of `l`: `7`
Add to `sum` --> `sum` is now `8`

Take third element of `l`: `4`
Add to `sum` --> `sum` is now `12`

Return `sum` --> `sum` is `12`

Might I suggest that `sum([1,7,4])`, the builtin python method would also work.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies. But if you supplant the `Return` with `Print` it will still give you a `12 none`. Meanwhile, in the first example I gave at the top, it will list out the sums {1,8,12) instead of giving an aggregate sum.

Comment: @user3386440, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Can you please provide a line of code in reference

Comment: @user3386440, For the first set of code, you are printing each line out and are using `{}`. Use `[]`

Comment: absolutely. How do I add in a line of code in comments without breaking formatting? Should I just add it to the OP?

Comment: @user3386440, Yes you might as well add it to your question as `[EDIT] @sshashank124` or something like that

Comment: @user3386440, Answer to your question update, if your block is not inside a function, you can't use `return` since it has nothing to `return` to. Instead you have to use `print`. `Return` is only used in methods

Comment: That was what thefourtheye said as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3386440, it has to do with the indentation of your `print` statement. In the first one, your `print` statement is in the `for` and therefore it prints for every time you run the code in the `for` loop whereas your second one is outside the `for` loop and therefore prints the final value. Also, the reason you get `none` is because when you are printing your call to the method however the method returns nothing or `none`. It only prints it. This is because you changed your `return` to `print`

Comment: Perfect! This is finally becoming more and more clear to me. I appreciate all your help. If only I could give rep to all of you guys!

Comment: @user3386440, You can! You can upvote as many answers as you like. That also gives rep

Answer (score 1):

In Python you will realise that when you initialise a variable you don't need to assign a type to it, you can just initialise anything in there.
in this case l was interoperated as an object, or an array to be specific.

as for the loop.

```
for number in l:
```

is like a for each statement, it goes through each of the elements. and stores it in number, then iterates after the block is executed, moving on to the next l.

Hope that helped? (if i understand your question.